# How to build JS.Class

Tags: javascript, js.class

I'm feeling completely stupid, but I can't find the correct way to build [JS.Class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/packages/bundling.html).
What I mean by building is merging all javascript files into one and minimize them.
I'm ok with other tools (different from what they suggested).

I tried with command line they suggest but

1. I don't have a manifest file (or I don't understand which is) so I don't know what put inside it and it's not human that I spend 1 day to bundle some javascript files
2. Jake doesn't work for me, throwing some errors, maybe because I'm using windows

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Are you open to using another tool besides JS.Class?  I have experience with another tool that is rather easy and will definitely work out of the box with Windows.

Comment: You write your own manifest file using the example on the homepage.

Comment: @JimmyMiller: yea no problem, I just need to merge those javascripts! rxgx: Mh I didn't notice there were an example, still I have to write the name of all modules to build a single JS? I definitely prefer another tool so :\

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL, can the solution depend on the .NET framework?  I'm trying to find a solution for you that requires the least external dependencies.  What about Java?  Is that installed?  What web platform are you using?  PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby on Rails on Windows through Cygwin?

Comment: I'm on MS Windows, whatever dependency you want I'll install it. All things you have mentioned are already on my computer (I don't need to merge those javascripts at runtime, I'm ok with merging them before uploading on the website!). I think there is already a tool for something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by myself with [yuicompressor](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/), thanks a lot to everyone